# where is my swift package after i build it?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

where is my swift package after i build it? (is it banished to some obscure location like derived data?)

Can I change the output PATH of the library I just built?

If so, how would I use "./" so the path is relative to the Package.swift file and I can see and copy the library I just built?

Comment: Im familiar with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-binary-frameworks-as-swift-packages - binaryTarget. Nothing shows up at the path I specify. Half the time I see "build succeeded" but then also a red 'x' and/or XCODE takes away my option to select a build target (by this I mean to let me select to build for iOS, versus macOS etc.)

Comment: Got the same question, frustrating that its not mentioned in the documentation. Where does it go?